# Accessing an array in an object

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP I printed `return '<pre>'.print_r($getFileId,true).'</pre>';` which is an object. This returns:

```
<pre>Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
  (
    [items:protected] => Array
      (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
      )

  )
```

How can I access the last element of the array. Tried `end($getFileId)` but it returned:

```
<pre>Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
  [2] => 3
)
</pre>
```

Comment: You can only access it in the class or in a class which extends from it

Comment: How about using the appropriate [methods for the collection class](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html), like the [all() method](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_all) or the [last()](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_last) method if you only want the last item.... read the Laravel API docs, and they might prove helpful

Comment: just use the pertinent method for getting the items with that collection object. something like `->toArray()` or something else

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm not into OOP and how should the code look like use the all()? `$getFileId->all()` ?

Comment: `$lastItem = $getFileId->last();` If you're going to use Laravel, and you're not into OOP, then you'd better get into OOP pretty quickly

Comment: The last() method did the task, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your Illuminate object has a method specifically for this purpose:

`$getFileId->last();`

Please see [the docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your `$getFileId` variable is a Collection object, not an array. That's why calling the `end` function on it does not work, but it doesn't fail either because it implements `ArrayAccess`.

You could do it in many ways:

```
end($getFileId->all());

$getFileId->flip()->first();

//beware, this one alters the collection by also removing the last element
$getFileId->pop();

$getFileId->slice($getFileId->count() - 1, 1)->first();
```

But all these would be just running in circles when you could simply do:

```
$getFileId->last();
```